# How to run java web application bundle in karaf runtime environment

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

I am trying to deploy a simple web application java bundle into karaf. I have created a bundle via the maven plugins: "maven-bundle-plugin" and "maven-scr-plugin". Everything seems to be ok, all dependencies have been added with  tag. Just for reference this is how my plugins look:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.25.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-scr-scrdescriptor</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>scr</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>
                            ${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}
                        </Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Name>${project.name}</Bundle-Name>
                        <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
                        <Bundle-Activator>
                            vaadin.visual.FrontEndActivator</Bundle-Activator>
                        <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

However when i try to run the bundle in karaf it is always in state **INSTALLED**

```
12 | Installed |  80 | 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | vaadin
23 | Active    |  80 | 4.2.8          | Apache Karaf :: OSGi Services :: Event
63 | Active    |  80 | 4.14.0         | Apache XBean OSGI Bundle Utilities
64 | Active    |  80 | 4.14.0         | Apache XBean :: Classpath Resource Finder
85 | Active    |  80 | 7.2.0          | org.objectweb.asm
86 | Active    |  80 | 7.2.0          | org.objectweb.asm.commons
87 | Active    |  80 | 7.2.0          | org.objectweb.asm.tree
```

and whenever i try to start the bundle with:

> bundle:start vaadin

Then i get the following error:

> Unresolved requirements: [[home.overtime.vaadin [12](R 12.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.bea.portlet.container)]

As from my understanding the container has fullfilled all dependencies that i have added to the pom but it requires some sort of web container which needs to provide stuff as the formentioned portlet container and some other web dependencies(Which i have not declared explicitly).

So my biggest concern is how do i start the web container to satisfy these dependencies?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which Vaadin version you are using?

Comment: @TatuLund vaadin 7